# Question: how to use the current time in a where clause

Tags: sql, mysql, phpmyadmin

there was a question coming up to my mind. Is there any possibility to use the current timestamp instead of a selected date in the Where Clause?

```
SELECT this, that
FROM here
WHERE start>='2010-07-01'
```

I thought it would be sth. like: start='now()' or curdate() or curtime().
Anything I found was that they're used in the Select Clause, but I need it in Where.

Any help is much appreciated.
Flora

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT this, that
FROM here
WHERE start >= NOW()
```

Comment: Be careful with NOW() when dealing with dates, as it returns time part too. In this specific case, you'll be fine, because you use >=.

Comment: Also according to a quick test NOW() doesn't work for instance in Oracle, so if you ever end up migrating to another DB, you'll have some additional work ahead if you go with NOW().

Answer (score 4):

You can use any of the following three functions as per your requirements:

```
SELECT NOW(),CURDATE(),CURTIME()
```

The output of this query is -

```
NOW()                | CURDATE()    | CURTIME()
---------------------+----------------+----------
2008-11-11 12:45:34  | 2008-11-11   | 12:45:34
```

Edited:
you can use these functions in Where clause as instructed.

Answer (score 2):

```
... WHERE v_date=CURRENT_DATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can:

```
WHERE start >= CURDATE()
```

You can use any expression in the `WHERE` clause, using any [inbuilt Date-and-Time function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'd use

```
WHERE start >= current_timestamp
```

Just because this should work in every DBMS. Don't know about NOW() though, maybe that's a standard function?

Update: well now I know NOW() does not work at least in Oracle, so I'd definitely go with current_timestamp, current_date etc, because these are in the standard. I've done a couple of DBMS migrations (DB2 -> MySQL, MySQL -> Oracle etc) and I'm glad we used the standards -compliant SQL where ever possible, which made the migrations relatively painless.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't to quote a function name

Use function names like this:

- `SELECT this, that FROM here WHERE
  start >= NOW();`
- `SELECT this, that FROM here WHERE
  start >= CURRENT_DATE();`